# Only process coordinates in a grid that haven't been processed yet

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm that lets me select multiple cells in a table when holding down left click without the need to select each cell again and again when a new one is selected.

For example, here the table has one selection:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      selected       |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

If I move the mouse to the cell next to it, the table should look like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      selected       |     selected     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And if I move it down from here:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      selected       |     selected     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      selected       |     selected     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

That should of course work in every direction.

Code-wise I have a coordinate system that gives me the user selection in this form:

```
type Coordinates = {
  startCoordinate?: {
    rowIndex: number,
    columnIndex: number
  },
  endCoordinate?: {
    rowIndex: number,
    columnIndex: number
  }
}
```

So the coordinates for the third table would look like this:

```
{
  startCoordinate: {
    rowIndex: 1,
    columnIndex: 0
  },
  endCoordinate: {
    rowIndex: 2,
    columnIndex: 1
  }
}
```

If that system doesn't work, it's fine to use something else. This is just what I felt to be enough information for this task.

What I did so far is simply deleting each selection and reselect everything including the new cells. That, however, is pretty bad performance-wise.

I should have everything I need to do this, so there's no need to give a full answer with HTML and stuff. An algorithm in pseudo code would be more than enough. I'll gladly give you some more information or the algorithm I have so far if that helps in any way.

EDIT:
Here's the function I've been using up until now

```
const forEachInSelectedRange = (func: (rowIndex: number, column: string) => void, grid?: dxDataGrid) => {
if (window.coordinates.startCoordinate && window.coordinates.endCoordinate) {
    // Get the min and max row index (if we select from the bottom up, the coordinates are swapped)
    const minRowIndex = Math.min(window.coordinates.startCoordinate.rowIndex, window.coordinates.endCoordinate.rowIndex);
    const maxRowIndex = Math.max(window.coordinates.startCoordinate.rowIndex, window.coordinates.endCoordinate.rowIndex);
    const columns = grid?.getVisibleColumns();

    if (columns) {
        // I'm using a library for the grid
        // I can't use column indexes because there are issues when moving the columns
        // Because of that, I use a unique field of the column (dataField) and get the corresponding index
        const startCol = columns.findIndex(c => c.dataField === window.coordinates.startCoordinate!.columnDataField);
        const endCol = columns.findIndex(c => c.dataField === window.coordinates.endCoordinate!.columnDataField);
        // Same as above, if we select from right to left, the coordinates are swapped
        const minColIndex = Math.min(startCol, endCol);
        const maxColIndex = Math.max(startCol, endCol) + 1;
        // Here I'm just reverting my indexes back to those unique strings, as it makes computing easier
        const selectedColumns = columns.slice(minColIndex, maxColIndex).map(c => c.dataField ?? '');

        // This is where I assume the performance issues arise
        // Since I have two nested loops, the calculation gets more expensive with each row/column that is selected
        // The table can have up to 150 rows and 25 columns
        // which means up to 3750 css class additions
        for (let rowIndex = minRowIndex; rowIndex <= maxRowIndex; rowIndex++) {
            for (const column of selectedColumns) {
                func(rowIndex, column); // Only adds the css class
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if your approach is the best, but nevertheless here is a working demo. I tried my best to comment the code instead writing a detailed answer here.

The main part of this technique is computing x and y positions from an index. You can read more about it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41e03d07-bb56-4702-bd08-973d1958394c/how-to-find-the-xy-coordinate-of-an-element-in-a-pixel-array-?forum=wpf)

The code loops over only the affected cells.

```
// ❗Instead of looping over all of the cells, we can compute the start and end index from the start / end coordinates
// This way we are looping over only the affected cells
let startIdx = startCoordinate.columnIndex + columnsCount * startCoordinate.rowIndex
let endIdx = endCoordinate.columnIndex + rowsCount * endCoordinate.rowIndex

if (startIdx > endIdx) {
  let temp = startIdx
  startIdx = endIdx
  endIdx = temp
}

for (let i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++) {
  const cell = cells[i]
  // Store the selected cell so you can remove the .selected class on mouseup
  selectedCells.push(cell)
  cell.classList.add('selected')
}
```

```js
const startCoordinate = {
  rowIndex: -1,
  columnIndex: -1
}
const endCoordinate = {
  rowIndex: -1,
  columnIndex: -1
}

// Grab the container div and all cells inside it
const containerDiv = document.getElementById('wrapper')
const cells = [...containerDiv.children]

cells.forEach((cell, i) => { cell.innerText = `${i}`})

// Grab the clear button
const clearBtn = document.getElementById('clear')

// You need to know the size of your grid in x and y dimensions
const columnsCount = 4
const rowsCount = 4

// Cache the indices of the selected cells, so you can unselect them on mouseup without looping over all of them

const selectedCells = []

let isMouseDown = false

const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'DIV') {
      // Find the index of the clicked cell
      const clickedCellIndex = cells.indexOf(e.target)
      // Find the x and y positions of your cell in the grid
      const startX = clickedCellIndex % columnsCount
      const startY = (clickedCellIndex - startX) / rowsCount
      // Store them
      startCoordinate.columnIndex = startX
      startCoordinate.rowIndex = startY
      // isMouseDown controls wether to autoselect them as you are hovering around the grid
      isMouseDown = true
    }
}

function onMouseStop () {
  isMouseDown = false
}

const onClearClick = e => {
  // reset the state when you stop hovering
  startCoordinate.columnIndex = -1
  startCoordinate.rowIndex = -1
  endCoordinate.columnIndex = -1
  endCoordinate.rowIndex = -1
  for (let i = 0; i < selectedCells.length; i++) {
    const cell = selectedCells[i]
    cell.classList.remove('selected')
  }
  selectedCells.length = 0
}

const onMouseMove = (e) => {
  // Run this logic only if the mouse is down
  if (isMouseDown) {
      if (e.target.nodeName === 'DIV') {
        // Find the index of the cell you are currently hovering on
        const clickedCellIndex = cells.indexOf(e.target)
        // Find its x and y positions in the grid
        const endX = clickedCellIndex % columnsCount
        const endY = (clickedCellIndex - endX) / rowsCount
        endCoordinate.columnIndex = endX
        endCoordinate.rowIndex = endY
        
        // ❗Instead of looping over all of the cells, we can compute the start and end index from the start / end coordinates
        // This way we are looping over only the affected cells
        let startIdx = startCoordinate.columnIndex + columnsCount * startCoordinate.rowIndex + 1
        let endIdx = endCoordinate.columnIndex + rowsCount * endCoordinate.rowIndex
        
        if (startIdx > endIdx) {
          let temp = startIdx
          startIdx = endIdx
          endIdx = temp + 1
        }
        
        for (let i = startIdx; i <= endIdx; i++) {
          const cell = cells[i]
          const x = i % columnsCount
            const y = (i - x) / rowsCount
            const checkBoundsX = (x) => (x >= startCoordinate.columnIndex &&
                                        x <= endCoordinate.columnIndex) ||
                                        (x <= startCoordinate.columnIndex &&
                                        x >= endCoordinate.columnIndex)
            const checkBoundsY = (y) => (y >= startCoordinate.rowIndex &&
                                        y <= endCoordinate.rowIndex) ||
                                        (y <= startCoordinate.rowIndex &&
                                        y >= endCoordinate.rowIndex)
            if (
              // Check if they intersect between startCoordinate and endCoordinate in x dimension
              checkBoundsX(x) &&
              // Check if they intersect between startCoordinate and endCoordinate in y dimension
              checkBoundsY(y)
            ) {

              // Store the selected cell so you can remove the .selected class on clear
              selectedCells.push(cell)
              cell.classList.add('selected')
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }

containerDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown)
clearBtn.addEventListener('click', onClearClick)
containerDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove)
containerDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseStop)
containerDiv.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseStop)
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; user-select: none; } 
.cell {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.selected {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
<button id="clear">clear</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this one also loops over every cell, which is exactly what I want to avoid. I at least think that that's my problem, since the selction gets slower with every row/column I add to the selection. What I had in mind was saving the latest state the grid was in and only loop over the cells, that ware not already in that previous state. I should also metion that I don't have checkboxes, but set the css class of the cells in a table. Although that probably doesn't really matter for the algorithm itself

Comment: I updated my example to not loop over each cell and to use divs instead of checkboxes

Comment: Thanks for going through all the trouble! Your answer is now more or less what I've been using up until now. I've updated my question to include my function. As I was reviewing that, it occured to me, that the performance issues might not come from the loops as there are only around 4000 loops max. That isn't enought to actually give me a second of delay after each selection right?

Comment: second of delay seems like way too much for modern browsers. Does your `.active` cell class triggers relayouting, i.e. are you changing their borders, paddings, etc? Are you executing your posted method on each new hovered pixel? Perhaps you can throttle your `mousemove` event or execute it only when a new cell is hovered?

Comment: Not as far as I know. It really only sets the background color. My function is executed when a new cell in the table is hovered and then only once, even if I move around inside the cell. 

After a bit of testing I think it's the library that's being slow. I'm getting the html cell by calling a function on the grid and I guess that's just really slow. Maybe I can work around that somehow.

Again thanks the help! I'll mark your answer as correct, since it practically does what my question asked for.

Comment: glad i could help :)